# Connect openCV to raspberry pi camera

Tags: node.js, opencv

I am using a raspberry on board camera.
I have installed OpenCV in raspberry pi.
I have also installed node-OpenCV.
OpenCV is unable to connect to my on board camera because it is always searching for the USB camera.

So is there any way to connect my onboard camera with OpenCV.

Comment: did you enable the camera? Read http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/30/accessing-the-raspberry-pi-camera-with-opencv-and-python/

Answer (score 1):

This command 
`sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2`

 will make /dev/video0 available so you can access it from your node app.

 This will have to run every time the pi boots